# how to check if element is fully visible into view port in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have gone many Stack Overflow answer for the same question and i am able to get if the element is visible but even if the element is little visible i am getting true.

I have total of 40 elements same class with 1,2 .. appended to it. here is my code

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var total = $(".singleElement").length;
    for(var i=1;i<=total;i++){
        var top_of_element = $(".singleElement."+i).offset().top;
        var bottom_of_element = $(".singleElement."+i).offset().top + $(".singleElement."+i).outerHeight();
        var bottom_of_screen = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).innerHeight();
        var top_of_screen = $(window).scrollTop();

        if ((bottom_of_screen > top_of_element) && (top_of_screen < bottom_of_element)){
                var myID = $(".singleElement."+i).attr("data-my_id");
                console.log(myID);
        }
    }
});
```

now when I scroll, so as soon as second element is visible, not entirely, i got the id but at the same time i get the id of first element as well. What i want is if previous element is entirely disappear and next one is on the screen fully then i should get the id.

Comment: It would be better if you share your elements as well. i.e need to see when your elements return true or false with scrolling.

Comment: how can I share elements? can't share the developing website because of security. let me know any other way

Comment: [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) can be the best way of sharing your current working example.

Comment: make a jsfiddle and put your chunk of working code there we can see it then. Thanks!

Comment: It is almost not possible for me to write that short of code.. one section is quite big and then need to do the changes so that actual code should not expose